# Can ice burn you from it being hot (not a frost bite sort of burn)?

Tags: pressure, water, phase-transition, ice

The phase diagram of water implies that at a high enough pressure (100 kbar) that very hot 300°C ice can exist. Researching about ice burning someone just nets results on frost bite (which is different here), and I can't seem to find any existence of this phenomena (nor have I seen any picture/experiments discussing it).

The same could be said for applying a bit of extra pressure to 101°C vapor and it should convert to liquid, but I haven't seen any videos producing this either.

Am I interpreting this phase diagram correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Although putting ice in contact with your skin at 1GPa, the heat is going to be the least of your worries.

Keeping water liquid at 101 degC is easy - that's why you have a pressure cooker.

Comment: 1) My greatest worry is not seeing this happen, my next worry, as you astutely stated, is experiencing it. :) Seems like if there's lots of videos on critical fluids and water at its triple point, you'd see something like this happen just as much. There's likely a reason why it's not happening. 2) True on the pressure cooker. I'd say it seems strange there's so many experiments on YouTube but seeing 101C water vapor get put in a syringe and compressed should result in seeing it shift to a liquid. Seems like an easy experiment.

Comment: Some of use need a pressure cooker to get liquid water at 100C (or even 96C or so).

Comment: @JonCuster - hence the British strategic decision to withdraw in 1776. Once it was discovered that you couldn't make a decent cup of tea in Denver there didn't seem much point in keeping the place

Comment: @MartinBeckett - now you are just _begging_ for a holy war on the appropriate temperature of water to make a good cup of tea! The Highlands of Scotland may rise in revolt again!